# A question on 45:23

Tags: quran, tafseer

In the following translations, the bold section confuses me, for they do not sound the same:

> **Sahih International:** Have you seen he who has taken as his god his [own] desire, and Allah has sent him astray **due to knowledge** and
> has set a seal upon his hearing and his heart and put over his vision
> a veil? So who will guide him after Allah ? Then will you not be
> reminded?
>
> **Yusuf Ali:** Then seest thou such a one as takes as his god his own vain desire? Allah has, **knowing (him as such)**, left him astray,
> and sealed his hearing and his heart (and understanding), and put a
> cover on his sight. Who, then, will guide him after Allah (has
> withdrawn Guidance)? Will ye not then receive admonition?
>
> **Shakir:** Have you then considered him who takes his low desire for his god, **and Allah has made him err having knowledge** and has set a
> seal upon his ear and his heart and put a covering upon his eye. Who
> can then guide him after Allah? Will you not then be mindful?
>
> **Muhammad Sarwar:** Have you seen the one who has chosen his desires as his lord? **God has knowingly caused him** to go astray, sealed his
> ears and heart and veiled his vision. Who besides God can guide him?
> Will they, then, not take heed?
>
> **Mohsin Khan:** Have you seen him who takes his own lust (vain desires) as his ilah (god), **and Allah knowing (him as such)**, left
> him astray, and sealed his hearing and his heart, and put a cover on
> his sight. Who then will guide him after Allah? Will you not then
> remember?
>
> (See for example [here](https://legacy.quran.com/45/23))

The translations, as given, do not make complete sense, neither do they agree with each other. (And it is not just a minor variation. For example the Sahih International translation where it says **due to knowledge** means nothing at all!) One Turkish translation I came across made complete sense but I did not see it elsewhere, where the relevant section was translated as: **Allah let him go astray [because he chose to go astray with his free will despite his knowledge and the fitrah inside of him]** ...

Can someone shed more light?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/tafsir_ibn_kathir/page/n5303/mode/2up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify let us look at that specific part of the verse alone with a simple word by word translation:

> وَأَضَلَّهُ ٱللَّهُ عَلَىٰ عِلْمٍ
>
> And Allah caused him to go astray upon knowledge

The question is whether the "upon knowledge" describes "Allah" or describes "him." So, the two options are:

> And Allah with Allah's knowledge caused him to go astray.
>
> And Allah caused the disbeliever to go astray while the disbeliever is with knowledge.

**Describes Allah**

Imam At-Tabari says:

> يقول تعالى ذكره: وخذله عن محجة الطريق، وسبيل الرشاد في سابق علمه على علم منه بأنه لا يهتدي، ولو جاءته كل آية.
>
> Allah says: And He refrained from helping him to the correct course and the path of guidance in His pre-existing knowledge about him that he would not be guided even if every sign came to him. ([Tafsir At-Tabari 93/21](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/39233#p1))

Then, he quotes a narration from Ibn Abbas with this interpretation:

> عن ابن عباس ﴿وَأَضَلَّهُ اللَّهُ عَلَى عِلْمٍ﴾ يقول: أضله الله في سابق علمه.
>
> Ibn Abbas said (on) {*And Allah caused him to go astray upon knowledge*}: Allah caused him to go astray in His pre-existing knowledge. ([Tafsir At-Tabari 93/21](https://al-maktaba.org/book/7798/39233#p1))

An-Nahhas in his Ma'aani Al-Quran says:

> رُوي عن ابن عباس أنه قال: ﴿عَلَىٰ عِلْمٍ﴾ قد عَلِمَه عنده.
>
> It is narrated from Ibn Abbas that he said: {*upon knowledge*} which He already knew from before. ([Ma'aani Al-Quran 437/6](https://al-maktaba.org/book/940/3063#p1))

Here, the meaning is that Allah caused him to go astray knowing that the man would not accept guidance.

**Describes "him"**

An-Nahhas also adds:

> وقيل: ﴿عَلَىٰ عِلْمٍ﴾ أنه لا ينفعه، ولا يضرُّه.
>
> And it is said: {*upon knowledge*} that it (his gods or desires) will neither benefit nor harm him. ([Ma'aani Al-Quran 437/6](https://al-maktaba.org/book/940/3064#p1))

In this interpretation, the verse means that the man was already given knowledge about the falsehood of his beliefs but he suppressed or ignored it.

**Conclusion**

It seems the first is a more popular interpretation which is why the translations you quoted use it more. However, in my opinion, the double meaning is intended.

Imam Qurtubi says:

> ثُمَّ قِيلَ: "عَلى عِلْمٍ" يَجُوزُ أَنْ يَكُونَ حَالًا مِنَ الْفَاعِلِ، الْمَعْنَى: أَضَلَّهُ عَلَى عِلْمٍ مِنْهُ بِهِ، أَيْ أَضَلَّهُ عَالِمًا بِأَنَّهُ مِنْ أَهْلِ الضَّلَالِ فِي سَابِقِ عِلْمِهِ. وَيَجُوزُ أَنْ يَكُونَ حَالًا مِنَ الْمَفْعُولِ، فَيَكُونُ الْمَعْنَى: أَضَلَّهُ فِي حَالِ عِلْمِ الْكَافِرِ بِأَنَّهُ ضَالٌّ.
>
> Then, it is said: "*upon knowledge*" can be a description of the subject, the meaning: He led him astray upon the knowledge of His about him i.e. He led him astray knowing that he is from the people of misguidance in His pre-existing knowledge.
>
> And it can be a description of the object, so the meaning would be: He led him astray in the state that the Kafir knows that he is astray. ([Tafsir Qurtubi 169/16](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31702/6093))

Both meanings are in essence true. Allah knows everything (which I don't need to prove). And people are misguided after knowledge comes to them. Allah says:

> And We gave them clear proofs of the matter [of religion]. And they did not differ except after knowledge had come to them - out of jealous animosity between themselves. Indeed, your Lord will judge between them on the Day of Resurrection concerning that over which they used to differ. ([45:17](http://quran.com/45/17))